# UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed() equivalent in REST API (SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS)

Tags: rest-api, licenses, user-management, rest-service, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Is there a way to get the `UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed()` value from REST Call after the User is authenticated via oAuth?

My problem is I've an authenticated user in Customer's Org with a managed App installed that has licensing.

I can check in Apex using `UserInfo.isCurrentUserLicensed()`.

But is it possible to retrieve the same in REST API (SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would like to see an answer for this.  I suppose you could write your own REST service in Apex using that method.

Comment: @RichVel, Yes. That is the solution I'm using as of now.

Comment: I found this sample code for a license checking REST service, including a JavaScript client intended for a hybrid mobile framework, such as PhoneGap: http://blogs.developerforce.com/isv/2013/07/how-to-build-enterprise-mobile-apps-using-the-salesforce-platform.html - looks quite easy.